# Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': The parent content type specified by content type identifier 0x0101 does not exist

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, feature, visual-studio-2012

I have created 80 content types. some of them are inherited from some other content types. I have placed all the content types in feature in such an order that parent content types are at top. But when I deploy solution. I get this error:

Error   45  Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': The parent content type specified by content type identifier 0x0101 does not exist.

Any Idea how to solve this ??

Comment: Error says it all, there must be something that content depends on and doesn't exists, use ULS viewer to capture inside errors maybe.

Comment: Do your custom content types that inherit from Document (`0x0101`) have an ID that is preceded with a `00`? ie: `0x010100[some guid here]`.

Comment: yes my custom CTs preceded with a 0x01010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the ID of the content type you are deriving from (in your case it is 0x0101 i.e. Document Content Type). So, make sure 0x0101 is present by examining the content type in the SharePoint UI (Site Settings > Manage Content Types). You'll get an exception (as you're getting right now) on feature activation if it's not, or the Inheritance between Content Type is not being correctly set up.

**Having said about inheritance:**

For any child content types IDs, you can simply add `'01'` or `'02'` to the ID generated in the previous step. It is definitely not necessary to append `'00'` and another GUID. This will simplify the content types IDs generation process in such large scale developments.

Comment: It's not necessary but it's a standard convention that most developers adhere to. Sure, it's something you can miss out between declarations and usages so things can break, but as long as you and your team always uses the `00` or not and they stick to the teams agreed standard, all should be fine. Also, you can't really guarantee some other dev is gonna try and use `01` or `02` at the end as they develop theirs at the same time as yours.

Comment: `OO` separator is required if the suffix being added to the ID is a `GUID` and to make it unique (agree with the fact being used by most of developers) but the `01` and `02` approach makes it much more simple to generate unique IDs in large scale development. I myself use `OO` in most of implementations but expect developers to know both :)

Answer (score -1):

```
stsadm -o activatefeature -filename publishingresources\feature.xml –url siteurl  -force
```